# Apple Enterprise Developer Distribution Certificate appears in keychain, not in Xcode Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a contract developer, and have an app to be distributed via the client's Enterprise account. 
I've worked with other clients on Enterprise accounts, but for some reason, the "iPhone Distribution" certificate that I've added to my keychain for this client does not appear in Xcode Organizer.

When I import a mobileprovision for the app, Xcode complains there's no valid key pair.

The client has added me to their account; can only the developer who created the Enterprise Distribution certificate import it to a keychain? If I create a new distribution cert (not profile), does that invalidate the existing cert (used by other apps I have not worked on?)

Answer (score 6):

You will need the person who created the certificate to export it from their keychain. The certificate you download from the provisioning portal is a public key and does not contain the private key.

From Apple Tech Note about Code Signing

> Note: In the case of missing Private Keys for your certificates,
>   Automatic Device Provisioning can restore your certificate to the
>   keychain, but not the missing private keys.
>
> Transferring Your Identities Once you have a healthy working code
>   signing configuration set up it is recommended that you follow the
>   steps in section Transfer Your Developer Profile to Another Computer
>   of the Xcode 4 User Guide to create a backup of them. The backup can
>   be used to restore your working code signing configuration from
>   hardware failure, or to enable code signing on additional Macs,
>   partitions, or OS X user accounts of your choice. The backup
>   (.developerprofile file) once created contains all of the following
>   items:
>
> all iPhone Developer certificates in your keychain all iPhone
>   Distribution certificates in your keychain all Provisioning Profiles
>   in the Xcode Organizer > Devices tab > Provisioning Profiles section
>   under "Library" Note: While creating the backup of your identities you
>   will be asked to enter a brand new password. Be sure to remember as
>   you'll be asked to enter that password later to use the backup for its
>   intended purposes.

[Tech Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933)

Comment: +1 Export it as a p12 file with a password, get them to email it to you and you can double click to add it to your keychain after entering the password.

Comment: yeah its important to back up the private keys from the originating machine. This way when more Leads get added to the development team they can have the ability of code signing the distribution version.